# Calculate for the standard error

Tags: self-study, standard-error

The instructor of a Chemistry Laboratory Class, which is composed of 10 students, asked each individual to record the time it took for a certain chemical to change its color after the third trial. The data (in minutes) were as follows: 5.18, 9.02, 13.35, 10.91, 8.57, 9.24, 10.16, 8.01, 9.33, and 11.28. What is the margin of error for the estimate at 95% confidence?

$mean = 9.505\ $ mins

$\sigma = 2.0613\ $ mins

$E = 1.96 *\frac{2.0613}{\sqrt{10}}$

$E = 1.2776$

I'm pretty sure I solved it correctly but my answer isn't in the choices on my worksheet so I want to know if I actually answered it correctly.

[edit] : added choices

2.84 minutes, 2.46 minutes, 2.87 minutes, 2.69 minutes, 2.64 minutes, 2.33 minutes, 2.61 minutes, 2.71 minutes, 2.39 minutes, 2.30 minutes, 2.50 minutes, 2.92 minutes, 2.41 minutes, 2.57 minutes, 2.79 minutes

Comment: I don't know your course material but I'd say it was more common to use (sample size $-$ 1) in estimating the SD and t-based confidence intervals for the mean with a sample of 10.

Comment: using $n-1$ in estimating $\sigma$ gives me 2.1728, together with a t-tail value of 1.833 givies me $E = 1.2594$ ... this is still not in the choices tho...

Comment: Can you tell us the possible choices?

Comment: Here are all the possible choices : 2.84 minutes, 2.46 minutes, 2.87 minutes, 2.69 minutes, 2.64 minutes, 2.33 minutes, 2.61 minutes, 2.71 minutes, 2.39 minutes, 2.30 minutes, 2.50 minutes, 2.92 minutes, 2.41 minutes, 2.57 minutes, 2.79 minutes... and yes there are 15 choices..

Comment: The question title says standard error and  body text  requires computation of   margin of error . which one is your target ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to derive a value of about 2.69 minutes.

Let $\{x_1, ..., x_{N}\}$ denote the $N = 10$ observed values. The mean is indeed

$$\bar x = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i}{N} = 9.505\,.$$

We don't know the variance of the population. The sample standard deviation is

$$s = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} (x_i - \bar x)^2}{N-1}} \approx 2.172777\,.$$

Since the standard deviation of the *population* is unknown, we should use the $t$-distribution for calculation the confidence interval. However, you have to use the normal distribution to obtain a value of the margin of error that is present in the choices.

We compute the margin of error for a 95% confidence interval ($\alpha = .05$),

$$E = \Phi^{-1}\left(1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}\right) \frac{s}{\sqrt{N}} \approx 1.346677\,,$$

where $\Phi$ denotes the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution.

As you can see, margin of error $E$ is considerably lower than the values of the choices. I suppose, you have to find the full width of the confidence interval instead:

$$2 E \approx 2.69\,.$$

---

R code for these calculations:

```
x <- c(5.18, 9.02, 13.35, 10.91, 8.57, 9.24, 10.16, 8.01, 9.33, 11.28)
N <- length(x)
mu <- mean(x)
s <- sd(x)
alpha <- 0.05
E <- qnorm(1 - alpha / 2) * s / sqrt(N)
2 * E
# [1] 2.693353
```

Comment: "for a α = 0.95 confidence intervall " does not make a sense. It should be eithe stated as α =.05  or 95% confidence interval.

Comment: As you can see, error of margin E is considerably lower than the values of the choices. I suppose, you have to find the full width of the confidence interval instead:

2E≈2.69. This part is incorrect.

Comment: @subhashc.davar Do you know the correct approach?

Comment: i said - This part is incorrect.